# How do you know what each element maps to in a semi direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have this example in my lecture notes

> "Calculate the semid direct product, $H \rtimes Q$ where, where $H = C_7, Q = C_3, C_7 = \langle b | b^7 = 1 \rangle$."
>
> $Aut(C_7 \cong C_6$. Find all homomorphisms $\theta: C_3 \rightarrow C_6$ (except for the trivial one). We need all elements of order 3 in $C_6$. We have $2 = \varphi(3): \alpha^2$ and $\alpha ^4$.
>
> $$Aut(C_7) = \langle \alpha | \alpha^6 = 1 \rangle$$
>   $$\alpha : b \mapsto b^3$$
>
> Two types on non-commmutative SDP:
>
> $$C_3 = \langle a|a^3 = 1\rangle \hspace{1cm} \theta(\alpha) = \alpha^2 \hspace{1cm} \theta(\alpha) = \alpha^4$$
>
> $$ba = a \theta(a^{-1})(b) = a \alpha^2(b) = a \alpha^4(b)$$
>
> $ba = ab^4$ (because $3^4 \equiv4 \mod 7$)
>
> $\theta(a) = \alpha^4$
>
> $ba =  a \theta(a^{-1})(b) = a \alpha^{-4}(b) = \alpha^2(b)$
>
> $ba = ab^2$ (because $3^2 \equiv 2 \mod 7).$

Here's what I don't understand:

1) How do you know you map $\alpha: b \mapsto b^3$?

2) What does all the $ba = a\theta(a^{-1}(b)$ bit all mean?

Please could someone explain this? Thank you

EDIT: I found something in my notes saying "We need to specify some $\theta(a) \in Aut(C_n), \{C_n \rightarrow C_n\}, b \mapsto b^l, (l,n) = 1$". So we basically want to find some $l$ where the gcd$(l,n) = 1$. I.e $(l,7) = 1$. Clearly $(3, 7) = 1$ but why not $(5, 7)$, or is that because this $l$ must be the number of possible orders in our other group?

Comment: Are you comfortable with the definition of a semidirect product?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber A SDP is a map which maps a group $Q$ to the automorphism of some other group $H$? EDIT: No, not map. It's a group I think mapping $Q \rightarrow Aut(H)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step to answering your question is going to be understanding what a semidirect product actually is. A semidirect product $K\rtimes C$ can be defined in the following way.

Take elements of $K\times C$ (as sets; the cartesian product); these will be the elements of your group.  Now pick some homomorphism $\theta:C\rightarrow \text{Aut}(K)$ and write $\theta(c)=\theta_c$.  Define multiplication by $$(k_1,c_1)(k_2,c_2)=(k_1\theta_{c_2}(k_2),c_1c_2).$$
What you've got here is written $K\rtimes_\theta C$.  Sometimes when people write a semidirect product they leave the $\theta$ out (when they believe it's obvious which $\theta$ they're using) but it is important to understand that there are many different semidirect products between two different groups, depending on which $\theta$ you pick.

For a description of the semidirect product notation used in your lecture notes (writing the elements individually, like $k$ instead of $(k,1)$) take a look at [this pdf](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~bayer/S09/ModernAlgebra/semidirect.pdf).

Now that you've got this, you can manipulate expressions like they want you to.  All they are doing is showing you how the two different (nontrivial) semidirect products work formed by the two different different (nontrivial) homomorphisms $C_3\rightarrow C_6\cong \text{Aut}(C_7)$.  They are manipulating the expressions according to the rules of semidirect products to show you how the $\theta$ gives you the group presentations.

Comment: In that PDF, what does $h'$ mean? It come up just before Theorem 2.

Comment: It's just some other element of $H$, they take elements $h,h'$ in $H$.

Comment: Also, I don't really get what $\phi(k)(h)$ means. They say that it is the results of applying the automorphism $\phi(k)$ to the element $h \in H$. So does this mean $\phi(k)$ is my automorphism, i,e the isomorphism of some $k \in K$ to itself. Then when applying this autmorphism to $h$, I get the answer $\phi(k)(h)$?

Comment: Yeah, $\phi(k)$ is your element of $\text{Aut}(H)$.  I think it's a little confusing to write it like that which is why I called it $\phi_k$ above.

Comment: In my example, I still don't get where the $\alpha: b \mapsto b^3$ bit comes in? They don't mention anything like that in the PDF.

Comment: They're saying that $\text{Aut}(C_7)$ is cyclic and generated by the map $\alpha$, which is defined by sending $b$ to $b^3$. So they define two different homomoprhisms $C_3\rightarrow \text{Aut}(C_7)=\langle \alpha \rangle$, one which maps the generator of $C_3$ to $\alpha^2$ and one to $\alpha^4$.

Comment: Yeah but how do you know it goes to $b^3$ and not say $b^2$ or $b^{-1}$?

Comment: That part is just number theory.  They couldn't have picked $2$ because the multiplicative order of $2$ mod $7$ is only $3$.  They could have picked $5$ though.

Comment: So how would I go about trying to pick the right power to send it to my exam? I've not done any number theory yet, that module is next semester. EDIT: Oh, is that bit to do with the $(l,n) = 1$ bit I posted. Yes, from there they could pick either 3 or 5. I'm guessing they picked 3 as its the smallest.

Comment: Sorry, 1 more final question. What exactly is the group that he's made using the SDP then? What is the answer?

Comment: If they give you a problem where they actually have you compute something using the power, it should be of some small number, so just compute it by exhaustion.  Like you know that $2$ won't work because $2\equiv 2 \pmod 7$, $4\equiv 4 \pmod 7$, $8\equiv 1 \pmod 7$.  So move on to $3$, and compute $3\pmod 7$, $3^2\pmod 7$, $3^3\pmod 7$, $3^4\pmod 7$, and make sure you don't get $1$ until $3^6$.

Comment: Both groups are actually isomorphic to the Frobenius group $F_{21}$.

Comment: Yeah but if I was to write the answer to this question, would that just be $ba = ab^2$ and $ba = ab^4$?

Comment: I guess.  Depends on how your prof wants you to write it.  Probably $\langle a,b|a^3,b^7,b^a=b^2 \rangle$ and $\langle a,b|a^3,b^7,b^a=b^4 \rangle$.

Comment: Defo final question, whats $b|a^3$? I don't understand that group notation sorry. We're looking at the $b^2$ one first, so how does it go $a$ then $ba^3$ then $b^7$?

Comment: Just group presentation notation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_presentation

Comment: Ohhh, ok, so that means the first SDP is the set of elements $a,b$ where we have $a^3, b^7$ and $b^{a} = b^2$? Still, where does the $a^3$ and $b^7$ come from? Sorry if they're all silly questions, I just want to make sure I 100% understand the basics before I start doing the ones in Syloy theory

Comment: When you have a relation like $a^3$ without a lhs and a rhs it just means that $a^3=1$.  Which we get from the fact that $C_3=\langle a \rangle$.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you very much for your help!